# Добавление dblink в PostgreSQL на FireBird

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, firebird

Имеется две базы: PostgreSQL и FireBird

Нужно синхронизировать данные из FireBird в PostgreSQL. Узнал, что можно использовать dblink, но вопрос только как. Начал читать разные методички для PostgreSQL, но кроме команды на установку расширения `CREATE EXTENSION dblink;` ничего толком не понял. Пробовал задавать подключение на FireBird, проверял - соединение некорректно.

Был бы благодарен, если подсказали!

Если еще пригодится, с FireBird я взаимодействую через утилиту IBExpert

Answer (score 0):

`dblink` это довольно прямой биндинг на `libpq` и поддерживает только протокол postgresql. Поэтому, может работать только с другим postgresql либо с базой, корректно реализующей протокол именно postgresql.

Возможно сможет помочь механизм [FDW](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-foreign-data.html), в wiki проекта [упомянут](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers) проект [firebird_fdw](https://github.com/ibarwick/firebird_fdw/).

Но в общем исходя из задачи. Ни dblink ни fdw не являются механизмами логической репликации. Может быть, вам достаточно просто выгрузить данные в csv из базы-источника и загрузить через `copy` в postgresql?

Comment: К сожалению нет, не будет достаточно. Требуется именно синхронизация между двумя базами.

Comment: @kepeeennnddd Так ты получишь доступ к таблицам Firebird из PG. Зачем ещё какая-то синхронизация, если можно использовать данные напрямую?.. Ну и периодическое переливание в локальные таблицы если уж очень приспичило тоже никто не отменял.